# QTP, How to convert a decimal value (VarType = 14) to any other VarType like int, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm running the following query in UFT to retrieve a value from the database. It returns the correct number for me. The number is 21572939 but the vartype for the number is vbDecimal(14).

```
sqlMsgQuery = ("SELECT MAX(CONTNO)FROM SERIES A, CONTRACT B WHERE A.SERIES = B.SERIES AND B.SERIES = "&"'AAA-W'"&_
              "AND A.PARTY_ROLE IS NULL AND B.CONTNO BETWEEN 21573931 AND 21574930")
```

On the other hand, i have another variable that holds the same value but this value is being retrieve from an oracle application and the vartype is vbString(8)

my job is to verify if the the two numbers are equal and then write it to datatable. I've tried a lot but failed to convert a decimal value with a vartype(14) to int and compare it with the other string that i've converted to int already.

What i'm looking for:
1. Either a query that will convert the number into int in the database before it is sent to the variable so that i can use it as int
2. Or a vbscript function/code that will do the conversion.
3. Or any other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide by 10 and CLng it.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the SQL column CONTNO is 8, you need to create a variable with VBString(8) as data type for storing the result from the SQL query .
And modify the existing query like below.

```
     sqlMsgQuery = ("SELECT CAST(MAX(CONTNO) as VARCHAR (8))
           FROM SERIES A, CONTRACT B 
           WHERE A.SERIES    = B.SERIES AND B.SERIES = "&"'AAA-W'"&_
          "AND A.PARTY_ROLE IS NULL AND B.CONTNO BETWEEN 21573931 AND 21574930")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the required data to the data type you want using `CAST` in SQL.

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

When you get the column `CAST` it as (data_type you want) then compare. Make sure both are same `DATA_TYPE` and same `LENGTH`.